# Conditional filter of grouped factors - dplyr

Tags: r, group-by, dplyr

Say I have this sort of dataframe:

```
   day value group type id
1    1   0.1     A    X  1
2    1   0.4     A    Y  1
3    2   0.2     A    X  3
4    2   0.5     A    Y  3
5    3   0.3     A    X  5
6    3   0.2     A    Y  6
7    1   0.1     B    X  3
8    1   0.3     B    Y  3
9    2   0.1     B    X 11
10   2   0.4     B    Y 10
11   3   0.2     B    X 12
12   3   0.3     B    Y 12
13   1   0.1     C    X 12
14   1   0.3     C    Y 12
15   2   0.3     C    X  5
16   2   0.2     C    Y  5
17   3   0.2     C    X  3
18   3   0.2     C    Y  2
```

Data:

```
library(dplyr)
df1 <- data.frame(
day = rep(1:3,6),
value = c(0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.2,0.1,0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.3, 0.1,0.3,0.2,0.3,0.2,0.2),
group = rep(LETTERS[1:3], each=6)
) %>% 
  arrange(group,day) %>% 
  mutate(type=rep(LETTERS[24:25],9),
         id = c(1,1,3,3,5,6,3,3,11,10,12,12,12,12,5,5,3,2))  

df1
```

I want to filter this dataframe based upon a conditional filter.  I want to `group_by(day, group)` and if all `id` within each grouping are all equal, I want to `filter` out all rows of type Y but keep rows of type X.

I can do this by running a loop or through several steps of dataframe subsetting, but I was wondering if there is a one/two liner in `dplyr` or `data.table` that I am somehow overlooking.

This would be the desired output:

```
   day value group type id
1    1   0.1     A    X  1
3    2   0.2     A    X  3
5    3   0.3     A    X  5
6    3   0.2     A    Y  6
7    1   0.1     B    X  3
9    2   0.1     B    X 11
10   2   0.4     B    Y 10
11   3   0.2     B    X 12
13   1   0.1     C    X 12
15   2   0.3     C    X  5
17   3   0.2     C    X  3
18   3   0.2     C    Y  2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an one-liner with `data.table`.

We convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df1)`), grouped by 'day', 'group', `if` the `length` of `unique` elements of 'id' is 1, we get the Subset of Data.table (`.SD`) rows where 'type' is 'X' or `else` get the `.SD`.

```
library(data.table)#v1.9.6+
setDT(df1)[, if(uniqueN(id)==1) .SD[type=='X'] else .SD, .(day, group)]
#    day group value type id
# 1:   1     A   0.1    X  1
# 2:   2     A   0.2    X  3
# 3:   3     A   0.3    X  5
# 4:   3     A   0.2    Y  6
# 5:   1     B   0.1    X  3
# 6:   2     B   0.1    X 11
# 7:   2     B   0.4    Y 10
# 8:   3     B   0.2    X 12
# 9:   1     C   0.1    X 12
#10:   2     C   0.3    X  5
#11:   3     C   0.2    X  3
#12:   3     C   0.2    Y  2
```

Or if the 'type' is already ordered as in the example data

```
unique(setDT(df1), by = c('day', 'group', 'id'))
```

If not ordered,

```
unique(setDT(df1)[order(group,day, id, type)],by = c('day', 'group' , 'id'))
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(day = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 
3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L), value = c(0.1, 0.4, 0.2, 0.5, 
0.3, 0.2, 0.1, 0.3, 0.1, 0.4, 0.2, 0.3, 0.1, 0.3, 0.3, 0.2, 0.2, 
0.2), group = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", 
"B", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C"), type = c("X", "Y", 
"X", "Y", "X", "Y", "X", "Y", "X", "Y", "X", "Y", "X", "Y", "X", 
"Y", "X", "Y"), id = c(1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 6L, 3L, 3L, 11L, 10L, 
12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 2L)), .Names = c("day", "value", 
"group", "type", "id"), class = "data.frame", 
row.names = c(NA, -18L))
```

Comment: @jazzurro  Thanks, it was introduced sometime back.

Comment: I think I missed it till now. I am a bit behind for learning new functions these days. I will have a look of DT crane manual today.

Comment: @jazzurro The equivalent one in `dplyr` is `n_distinct`

Comment: Ah I see. Got it. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Similar to P Lapointe, I had the following. I initially wanted to use `all()` to check if all id values are identical or not, but that attempt failed. So, I chose to use `diff()`. Using `mutate()` I checked if all id values are identical or not for each group. Then, I chose rows which does not have the combination of `check == TRUE and type == "Y"`. Finally, I removed the check column.

```
group_by(df1, day, group) %>%
mutate(check = any(diff(id) == 0)) %>%
filter(!(check == TRUE & type == "Y")) %>%
select(-check)

#     day value  group  type    id
#   (int) (dbl) (fctr) (chr) (dbl)
#1      1   0.1      A     X     1
#2      2   0.2      A     X     3
#3      3   0.3      A     X     5
#4      3   0.2      A     Y     6
#5      1   0.1      B     X     3
#6      2   0.1      B     X    11
#7      2   0.4      B     Y    10
#8      3   0.2      B     X    12
#9      1   0.1      C     X    12
#10     2   0.3      C     X     5
#11     3   0.2      C     X     3
#12     3   0.2      C     Y     2
```

**EDIT**

After communicating with akrun, I revised the code above. Here it is.

```
group_by(df1, day, group) %>%
mutate(check = n_distinct(id) == 1) %>%
filter(!(check == TRUE & type == "Y")) %>%
select(-check)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
 df1 %>% group_by(day,group) %>% distinct(id)
```

Your original data is ordered, so it is ok, otherwise try

```
df1 %>% group_by(day, group) %>%
    arrange(group, day, type) %>% distinct(id) %>%
    ungroup %>%‌ ​arrange(group, day, type, id)
```

Comment: does this rely on the `type` variable being arranged in X-Y order? or does it do it based on factor level?

Comment: Yes, it does. So first `arrange(day, group, type)`

Comment: Your original data is ordered, so it is ok, otherwise try :df1%>%group_by(day,group)%>%arrange(group,day,type)%>%distinct(id)%>%ungroup%>%arrange(group,day,type,id)

Answer (score 1):

Here's my solution with `dplyr`.

```
df1%>%
group_by(day,group)%>%
mutate(len=length(unique(id))==1)%>%
filter(ifelse(len==TRUE,type=="X",type %in% c("X","Y")))

Source: local data frame [12 x 6]
Groups: day, group

   day value group type id   len
1    1   0.1     A    X  1  TRUE
2    2   0.2     A    X  3  TRUE
3    3   0.3     A    X  5 FALSE
4    3   0.2     A    Y  6 FALSE
5    1   0.1     B    X  3  TRUE
6    2   0.1     B    X 11 FALSE
7    2   0.4     B    Y 10 FALSE
8    3   0.2     B    X 12  TRUE
9    1   0.1     C    X 12  TRUE
10   2   0.3     C    X  5  TRUE
11   3   0.2     C    X  3 FALSE
12   3   0.2     C    Y  2 FALSE
```