# Filter in a dplyr group only when the condition is met else do not

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a `right_join` table where I have `NA` values for some columns depending on which table the entry originated from. Each "hit" in the table has an "indx" that begins with 0.

I want to `group_by(hit, indx)` and do some conditional filtering. I want to use `dplyr` preferably.

Here is the data:

```
test <- tibble(hit = c(rep("101mA", 4), rep("1914A", 5)), 
               indx = c(0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1),
               hit_start = c(7, 63, 105, 131, 4, 7, 56, 64, 147), 
               hit_end = c(112, 82, 126, 152, 82, 34, 83, 81, 166), 
               stamp_score = c(NA, 9.32, 9.30, 9.49, NA, NA, NA, 8.16, 9.15), 
               bit_score = c(76.2, NA, NA, NA, 84.7, 8.3, 0.3, NA, NA) 
              )
```

Here's the table:

```
# A tibble: 9 x 6
  hit    indx hit_start hit_end stamp_score bit_score
  <chr> <dbl>     <dbl>   <dbl>       <dbl>     <dbl>
1 101mA     0         7     112       NA         76.2
2 101mA     0        63      82        9.32      NA  
3 101mA     0       105     126        9.30      NA  
4 101mA     1       131     152        9.49      NA  
5 1914A     0         4      82       NA         84.7
6 1914A     0         7      34       NA          8.3
7 1914A     0        56      83       NA          0.3
8 1914A     0        64      81        8.16      NA  
9 1914A     1       147     166        9.15      NA
```

In each `group_by(hit, indx)`, if there is even a single `NA` in the "stamp_score" column, I want to keep the rows with the `NA` entries. However, I want to keep all rows if there is no `NA` in the "stamp_score" column for a group.

Here is what I expect at the end:

```
# A tibble: 6 x 6
  hit    indx hit_start hit_end stamp_score bit_score
  <chr> <dbl>     <dbl>   <dbl>       <dbl>     <dbl>
1 101mA     0         7     112       NA         76.2
4 101mA     1       131     152        9.49      NA  
5 1914A     0         4      82       NA         84.7
6 1914A     0         7      34       NA          8.3
7 1914A     0        56      83       NA          0.3
9 1914A     1       147     166        9.15      NA
```

Please note that I intend to eventually use the code for a table with >10000 hits, each with their own "indx".

Comment: what do you mean by "I do not want to filter any row if there is no `NA`?meaning that you want to drop the observations without NA or you want to keep them?

Comment: Sorry. I meant I want to keep all the rows if there are no `NA` values in the "stamp_score" column in the group.

Comment: Please, show the expected result. This would to better understand your intentions. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, I found the answer in another related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33715660/conditional-filter-of-grouped-factors-dplyr?rq=1).

This uses a `data.table` one liner which in my case was:

```
library(data.table)

test <- setDT(test)[, if(any(is.na(stamp_score))) .SD[is.na(stamp_score)] else .SD, .(hit, indx)]
```

Essentially, this code subsets the group only if there is a `NA` in the "stamp_score" column else it does not.

Thanks to everyone who tried to help and also helped me improve my question over time.

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure whether you want to keep the values with NA in stamp_score or drop them. but I think this should make the job:

```
library(dplyr)

# create the df where you only have group with non missing obs
noNAind <- test %>% group_by(indx) %>% filter(!any(is.na(stamp_score))) %>% ungroup()
noNAhit <- test %>% group_by(hit) %>% filter(!any(is.na(stamp_score))) %>% ungroup()

# create the df with all the missing obs 
missind<- test %>% group_by(indx) %>% filter(is.na(stamp_score)) %>% ungroup()
misshit<- test %>% group_by(hit) %>% filter(is.na(stamp_score)) %>% ungroup()

# merge the data
test<- full_join(noNAind,noNAhit) %>% distinct()
test<- full_join(test,missind) %>% distinct()
test<- full_join(test,misshit) %>% distinct()
```

Comment: Sorry, but with this code, no rows are kept for the group "indx" = 1

Comment: then you can later merge them?

Comment: Can you please tell me how? Please note that I ultimately have to do this for tens of thousands of rows.

Comment: I have edited the code, see if this works to achieve what you want

Comment: It works for this example. But I have a bigger table with many entries in the "hit" column. When I use this approach for the full table, it fails by dropping many unnecessary rows.

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you are looking for. I mean it should drop only the cases when they are part of a group where one of the observations has a `stamp_score` equal to `NA` and keep all of the other values. Regardless of the number entries in the "hit" column. btw they should be the same number of entry on any other column if it is a tibble.

Comment: Sorry for the lack of clarity. I have revised the dataset now. Please check. Thanks!

Comment: I have edited the code, see if this works for you.It might not be straightforward but should do the job

Comment: Thanks, but I'm sorry this does not work as well. Please note that I want to `group_by(hit,indx)`. So for a group of "hit" with certain "indx". I am editing the question again to illustrate this better...

Also, is there a typo in your code, because you seem to have created two "noNAhit" df's? The second one is overwriting the first one.